# Reverse linked list causes a loop

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

### Why does this cause a loop?

I am trying to do a reverse linked list using an iterative method, but a loop occurs when the head node is traverse (ex. print()). I've tried this with C# and had no problem (modified syntax of course).

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node* next;
};

void
Reverse(Node& head_ref) {

  Node* current = &head_ref, *next = nullptr, *prev = nullptr;

  while (current != nullptr) {
    next = current->next;
    current->next = prev;
    prev = current;
    current = next;
  }
  head_ref = *prev; //strange phenomenon happened here after head_ref is set.
}

int
main() {

  Node* head = new Node();
  Node* first = new Node();

  head->data = 1;
  head->next = first;

  first->data = 2;
  first->next = nullptr;

  Reverse(*head);

  while (head != nullptr) { // <-- infinite loop
    cout << head->data << endl;
    head = head->next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

***prev*** variable in ***Reverse(...)*** method on return:

```
0x0108ed10 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {data=1 next=0x00000000 <NULL> } }
    data: 2
    next: 0x00eff190 {data=1 next=0x00000000 <NULL> }
```

After ***head_ref*** is set it creates a cycle linked list:

```
0x0108ed10 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {...} } } } }
    data: 2
    next: 0x00eff190 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {data=2 next=0x00eff190 {...} } } } }
```

Comment: It's worth stepping through in a debugger to see if this is actually working correctly.

Comment: a loop occurs when the node is traverse (ex. print()). No clue why the code would cause a cycle linked list.

Comment: If you won't debug, at least print the pointers to see when they start reappearing.  That may give a clue.

Comment: If you inadvertently create a loop your print code will never stop running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head_ref = *prev;` overwrites a `Node` because `head_ref` is `Node&`, not `Node*&`. Whereas you intend to update `head` pointer, rather than an entire `Node` `head_ref` refers to.

One fix would be:

```
void Reverse(Node*& head) {
    Node* current = head;
    // ...
    head = prev;
}
// ...
Reverse(head);
```

Alternatively:

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head) {
    Node* current = head;
    // ...
    return prev;
}
// ...
head = Reverse(head);
```

Comment: The latter solution worked for me. Thanks! However, this code here didn't create a loop. void Reverse(Node& head_ref) {

 Node* temp = &head_ref;
 temp->data = 30;
 temp->next->data = 40;
 head_ref = *temp;

}

Comment: @Binary01 When implementing lists you may like to only ever use `Node*` for consistency.